# Unable to connect to CloudBees through Eclipse

Tags: cloudbees

I am trying to follow the tutorial here:  http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/Documentation/CloudBeesEclipseToolkit  that describes how to configure your eclipse to use the CloudBees subversion respository.  When I get to step 2, and try to validate my account username and password, I get:

```
Failed to validate your account.

Reason:
Failed to get account services info.
Authentication of user:  xxxx failed.;
```

Details -
    Unexpected response code:400. Message: Bad Request

I did use my google account (and oauth?) to create my cloudbees account.  I am using my google username and password to try to validate.

Answer (score 1):

The account name is what you see when you enter in cloudbees on the top right.

Regarding your missing password this is due to the fact that google and github sign in don't ask user to define a password - that's why you get an authentication failure.

Users can use https://grandcentral.cloudbees.com/account/forgot_password to request password reset and define the password.

Comment: Sounds right, but I would think that it would be better to ask for password creation when the user signs up for an account (or shortly after).  I think most people will try get the Eclipse configuration working before they start exploring the builds section of the website.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by clicking on the builds sectio of my account.  This led me to some pages that told me I didn't have a password with cloudbees, and prompted me to create one.

When I used this password, instead of my gmail one, validation worked.

Also, I had to use my account name minus @gmaail.com to perform svn checkins, which wasn't the most intuative - it's not clear what un/ow and where